# WordPress automatically removes line break

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, line-breaks

When writting a description for a Woocoomerce Product and inserting a line break with  **br**  or **p** Tag, WordPress automatically removes it. This is really annoying because on some points, i want to have a little line break.

I often found the solution to install TinyMCE. After that now WordPress doesnt removes the **p**  Tag anymore but inserts a **&nbsp** inside of it and so the line break is way to big.

So i want a line break like a **p** Tag, because **npsb** produces way too much space between two sentence.

I also tried following solutions:

1. add some attributes to the p Tag like  `<p data-x> </p>`
2. Wrap the p Tag with comments like

```
<!-- wp:html --> <p class="beer"></p> <!-- /wp:html -->
```

3. Added some hooks in the functions.php like

```
add_shortcode("br", "br_tag"); function br_tag(){ return("<br/>"); }
```

or

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
```

and

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' ); function wpse_wpautop_nobr( $content ) { return wpautop( $content, false ); } add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_wpautop_nobr' ); add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpse_wpautop_nobr' );
```

4. I tried following solution but it doesnt work [Wordpress automatically adding "&nbsp;"?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29702/wordpress-automatically-adding-nbsp)

The "best" solution i found was to NOT using the visual AND the text editor, but for me thats such a temporary one.

Specs:

WordPress 5.6

Advanced Editor Tools (previously TinyMCE Advanced): 5.6

WooCommerce: 4.6.1 (but in my opinion, its not a WooCommerce problem)

Does anyone know a better solution or a reference for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved Problem with activated the prevent "remove `<br>` and `<p>` tag" option and inserted a
`<p><!-- Break --></p>`
when using a `<p>` tag. The comment prevent that the tag would remove or filled with **&npsb**

Answer (score 0):

WordPress best practice is use as few plugin as possible , below method allow you inject line break without any 3rd party plugin

1. Go to Edit page\post screen , browser address bar shall navigate to something like this , https://www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=5&action=edit
2. Click [text editor](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/text-editor/)

3) Avoid writing `<p> , <br> or <span>` , use `<br class="">` in you want inject new line